# ignore parameter if null - Spring Boot JPA findby

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, null, findby

I need 4 filtering options to get a list.
so I used `findBy~And~` method in SpringBoot JPA.
But when some filterings is not applied, `null` data is passed.
so from the code below,
mysql proceed query like `select ~ where branch=""` which returns 0 row where it should return all the columns,,,,since branch filter is not applied.

SO I want it to ignore the parameter when it's `null` dynamically or not sending the parameter at all.

please kindly help !

service page :

```
Page<ReviewModel> reviewList = this.reviewRepository.findByBranchAndSexAndAgeRangeAndPurpose(request.getBranch(), request.getSex(), request.getAgeRange(), request.getPurpose(), pageable);
```

repository page:

```
Page<ReviewModel> findByBranchAndSexAndAgeRangeAndPurpose(String branch, String sex, String ageRange, String purpose, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Don't use a finder method, instead use a specification and build the query dynamically with specifications.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you ! you are my savior ❤